# Is this Rails association between Company and Employee valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm writing a basic CRM app to learn Ruby on Rails 4.2, and I have an odd pair of associations (or maybe not so odd).  If this were straight SQL and another platform it would be straightforward, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly in ROR.

The business requirement is that each company has one or more users.  Simple enough. (Relevant portions of the model below.)

```
user.rb    
belongs_to :company

company.rb
has_many :users
```

An additional requirement is that each company can have one primary user.  I need to be able to reference the user's info (name, email, etc) within a Companies index and show view.  This is where I'm kind of uncertain.  Should the models look like this (it doesn't make sense to me, but I can't think of another way)?:

```
user.rb
belongs_to :company

company.rb
has_many :users 
has_one :user
```

Here's an abbreviated schema.  The user_id in companies is the FK to store the "primary contact":

```
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "companyname"
    t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.integer  "company_id"
end
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user.rb    
belongs_to :company

company.rb
has_many :users
**belongs_to :primary_user, class_name: "User"**
```

in company you should have primary_user_id column. You can also define has_one on user like this:

```
user.rb    
belongs_to :company
**has_one :primary_company, class_name: "Company", foreign_key: "primary_user_id"**

company.rb
has_many :users
belongs_to :primary_user, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I'm going to try both approaches shortly.  For the sake of being as simple as possible, would you go with your first or second option?  To be clear: a company does **not** have to have a primary contact/user, but they can have up to one.

Comment: I went with the first option you suggested.  Created and ran migrations per my original posting, **plus** `primary_user_id` in `companies` table.  I populated a few users, and a few companies, then for test company "A", I added a foreign key of user 1.  In rails console, `user.find(1).company` returns a proper object, but `company.find(1).user` returns this error: NoMethodError: undefined method \`User\` for #<Company id: 1, companyname: \"A Corp\", primary_user_id: 1>
Did you mean?  users'

Comment: The first suggestion worked great, thanks.  The solution to my follow-up was this: once I got the proper data into the database, I could use `Company.find(1).primary_user`

Answer (score 0):

```
user.rb    
belongs_to :company

company.rb
has_many :users
```

Above models are proper. I think for the primary user of a company you can have one more model like primary_user_membership.rb

```
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user


  create_table "primary_user_memberships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your info, your model is correct.

```
user.rb    
belongs_to :company

company.rb
has_many :users
```

You can do `Company.first.users` to see all the first company's users.

Let's say User 1 is the Primary user of Company 1, in rails console, you can check by doing `Company.first.users.first`

You can also check User 1's info by doing :-

```
user1 = Company.first.users.first
user1.username
```

When you generate the User model, you can do: `rails g model User username email phone company:belongs_to`

Your schema model should look like:-

```
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "companyname"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.integer  "company_id"
end
```

Comment: A primary user is not necessarily the _first_ one (especially with the undefined sort order)

Comment: true that. should have created a primary user method in company.rb